# Ubuntu Restricted Extras for 14.04 32 bit

Tags: plugins

My ubuntu has not internet connection. Because I cant connect my modem there. Can anyone give me a good idea so that I can downlod the all media codec (ubuntu_restricted_extras.dev) for ubuntu 14.04 32 bit from my mobile and install it to my Laptop (ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: why don't you connect your mobile to your computer and use that as an internet connection?

Comment: His/her mobile phone? Depending what country they're in that could cost big $$$'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you a precise answer without knowing which mobile phone you have, but here's as much as I can explain:
On your mobile phone, download the 32 bit deb file from a mirror like: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/u/ubuntu-restricted-extras/

At present time the latest one is http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/u/ubuntu-restricted-extras/ubuntu-restricted-extras_61_i386.deb

Then transfer the file from your mobile phone to your laptop.

On your laptop, double click on the deb file, this will open up the software center where you can click 'Install'. At this point you will be prompted to type in your password to allow the installation.

Comment: Thankx. the file is 3 KB only. I've downloaded it and install it in my ubunbu 14.04 (32 bit). but no media file aren't working :-(

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, and you could try searching the site here for a solution, or post a different question after researching for a solution. What you asked was how to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package, and it sounds like you've accomplished that. :)